# Acer tree leaves are not growing

Tags: identification, trees, diagnosis, maple

I planted my acer tree last year and it bloomed throughout the year very well. i havent moved it at all. this year the leaves start to come, i can see new leaves bloom but they are dying before they can grow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Photographs, of the entire tree and of close-ups of the leaves, would help.

Comment: Do know which type of acer you planted? If you have the tag that presumably came with the tree, please tell us both the common name and the botanical name.

Comment: When adding photos/further information about the tree, please also say where you are in the world so we can work out what the weather has been like where you are.

Answer (score 1):

Leaves dying before reaching full size is a sign of stress. Round up the usual suspects. Look to the following to be sure you are in the right range or get rid of the problem.

- Temperature
- Light
- Water
- Toxic chemicals
- Fertilizer
- Insects
- Fungus
- Animal damage

For example, is the plant watered the right amount? Did somebody dump some weird chemical on the roots? Is it over fertilized? You get the idea.

Carefully inspect the entire tree, root to twig, and look for any signs other than the leaves dying. You might bring a magnifying glass and examine small details. Discolored? Scrape marks? Webs? You get the idea.